# Kinect color to depth mapping

Tags: c#, image-processing, kinect, emgucv

Given a color pixel coordinate(x,y), is there a way to find the corresponding depth image co-ordinate?
I looked into co-ordinate mapping, using which you can map a skeleton pixel to a color pixel. I'm identifying objects in the color stream and I want to know how far they are using the depth stream. Am I overlooking something here?

Answer (score 1):

DepthImagePoint headDepthPoint = depth.MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint(skel.Joints[JointType.Head].Position);

ColorImagePoint headColorPoint = depth.MapDepthPointToColorPoint. X, headDepthPoint. Y, ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);

like this try if there any methods like "MapColorPointToDepthPoint"